# Get Master Key from Mnemonic seed for Cardano Byron wallet

Tags: wallet, private-key, byron

I have wallet in Infinito wallet. My mnemonic seed has 12 words and Yoroi, Daedalus Wallet does not support it.

I can get different Master Private key, address for Cardano Shelley, Byron wallet from mobile wallet app.

I am going to get them from code.

The master private key of Cardano Shelley can be gotten by following code.

```
const rootKey = CardanoWasm.Bip32PrivateKey.from_bip39_entropy(
  Buffer.from(entropy, 'hex'),
  Buffer.from(''),
);
```

Ref: https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/cardano-serialization-lib/generating-keys#bip39-entropy

But I can't get the master private key of Cardano byron wallet.

How can I get the private key and address of Cardano byron wallet from mnemonic?

Comment: Can you share what error you are getting when you say you cannot get it with that function?

Comment: What prefix does your Byron wallet start with? `Ae2` or  `Dd`?

Comment: I don't get any error. I am getting another private key which is different from wallet app. Its prefix is `Ae2`

Comment: Actually, I am getting same private key as Cardano Shelley. I want to know if there is another way to get private key for Cardano byron

Comment: did anyone manage to recover the Ada Byron from Infinito wallet?

Comment: Hi @u30004 and welcome to the Cardano StackExchange. If you have a question about a new topic, please open a new question instead of posting an answer on a related question. Otherwise people will probably not see it and the likelyhood of getting an answer is close to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Your private key in infinito is the right one to use, you just have to find the correct deviation numbers. I was recently hired to recover a byron wallet from the same app (infinito-wallet), I'll be releasing the script publicly once I get permission.

Comment: I used Private key from infinito wallet, so I can manage to get wallet address. But when I submit transaction, I am getting error. https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/10994/transaction-submit-error-missingvkeywitnessesutxow. What do you think?

Comment: I can send you an invite to the private repository to view the copy of the script I made to recover the wallet (byron) from infinito. What's your github?

Comment: My github ID is `heindrick17`. Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/kcxyzxyz/restore-byron-ada-infinito-wallet made it public.

Answer (score 0):

The way you obtain the `rootKey` from the `mnemonic` is the same for both Shelley and Byron.

For Byron, you then have to do the following to get the right address:

```
const accountKey = rootKey
  .derive(harden(1852)) // purpose
  .derive(harden(1815)) // coin type
  .derive(harden(0)); // account #0

const utxoPubKey = accountKey
  .derive(0) // external
  .derive(0)
  .to_public();

const byronAddr = CardanoWasm.ByronAddress.icarus_from_key(
  utxoPubKey, // Ae2* style icarus address
 CardanoWasm.NetworkInfo.mainnet().protocol_magic()
);
```

You can have more information [here](https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib/blob/master/doc/getting-started/generating-keys.md).

Comment: I already tried it. But I am getting another byron address which is different from Infinito wallet address. I think Infinito wallet was using old way to get private key and wallet address. Is there any other way to get private key?

Comment: I am not familiar with Infinito wallet. Is it possible to ask their team on how they do it?

Answer (score 0):

Update*****. Byron era cardano that is stuck in Infinito wallets can be accessed and moved with the Moonstake wallet app. Tested and works. You import your wallet with your byron private key that Infinito gives you. Thanks to Hazel from the Infinito helpdesk.

There is quite a few of us with cardano stuck in our infinito byron wallet. Late 2022, they added a warning to the app to move our byron to shelly or it would become inaccessible. I had to roll back infinito app to previous version and sideload app install.  Most of us have our 12 word passphrase, private key, and public address. My public address shows the correct ada on block elporers.  Daedalus, yoroi (previous version) browser extension, and a few other wallets like adalite.io will accept 12 key passphrase, but will generate diff keys. So our ada is as of right now inaccessible. Infinito discontinued suppot and do answer emails as far as i know.  If any savy cardano-cl guys could write a script allowing us to insert our private keys and move our ada to shelly...thatd be real nice. Also worth paying a fee to the creator of such a script.  Becuase it is frustrating to have ur crypto stuck even though you have passphrase, pvtkey and pubkeys. I havnt found a solution with any known wallet yet.  The previous versions of infinito no longer have connectivity to a node i suppose. So, I, and many others are currently stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Side note, I emailed IOHK and Yoroi for help, they both responded promptly. But their solutions were to restore with daedalus or lacy.io, neither worked for me.